# Adding arrow (\draw) to pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I'm using

```
\definecolor{kitgreen}{rgb}{0,0.588235294117647,0.509803921568627}
\definecolor{kitblue}{rgb}{0.274509803921569,0.392156862745098,0.666666666666667}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
ycomb,
xmin=0,
xmax=21,
ymin=0,
ymax=1.2,
]

\draw[<->,red] (100,31) -- (100,80);   %why does this work?
\draw[<->,blue] (10,0.31) -- (10,0.8); %should work, but doesn't.

\draw[black,dashed] ({rel axis cs:0.95,0}|-{axis cs:0,1}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,1});
\draw[black,dashed] ({rel axis cs:0.95,0}|-{axis cs:0,0.8}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,0.8});
\draw[black,dashed] ({rel axis cs:0.95,0}|-{axis cs:0,0.31}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,0.31});
\addplot+ [semithick,color=black,mark=*,mark options={fill=white}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1 0.194\\
2 0.18\\
4 0.215\\
5 0.192\\
6 0.189\\
8 0.214\\
9 0.221\\
10 0.176\\
11 0.223\\
12 0.178\\
13 0.199\\
14 0.222\\
15 0.179\\
16 0.229\\
17 0.184\\
18 0.19\\
19 0.175\\
20 0.224\\
};
\addplot+ [semithick,color=kitgreen,mark=*,mark options={fill=white}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
3 0.8\\
};
\addplot+ [semithick,color=kitblue,mark=*,mark options={fill=white}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
7 0.31\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Why is the red arrow showing correctly (x scaled by 10, y scaled by 100) but the blue one isn't?
I would expect the blue arrow at x=10.

[image: result]

Comment: I think it works. You can see the lower blue arrow tip at (1,0), but the upper blue arrow tip is under the axis (hence not shown). You probably are mistaken by your scaling.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, the red one doesn't work, in that the position doesn't correspond to the coordinates used. That said, the reason it doesn't work is probably that by default, coordinates for `\draw` etc. inside an `axis` does not correspond to the axis coordinates. Use `(axis cs:1,1)` to explicitly use the axis coord system. Or add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` to the preamble, with that setting `(1,1)` and `(axis cs:1,1)` will work the same, because `axis cs` becomes default.

Comment: Thanks Torbjørn, i didn't know that. Can you formulate a full answer? I'll mark is as solved then.

Comment: Very likely a duplicate question can be found, so I'll look for that first. (By the way, if you write `@<username>`, e.g. @MarvinNoll, the user will be notified of your comment. You who posted the question is always notified of new comments, other users are not.)