# Line code not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates

`\draw[thick] (pi/4,0)--(pi/4,1);` is not working

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.14mm]
 \hspace{-0.4cm}\begin{axis}
    [
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={ultra thick},
    axis on top,
    tick style={black, thick,major tick length=6pt},
    xlabel = {},
    ylabel = {},
    xmin=-2, xmax=2,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1,
    xtick={-pi/4,pi/4},
    xticklabels={$-2$,$2$},
    ytick={0},
    yticklabels={},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.2}
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-1/2*pi:1/2*pi,samples=50,smooth,ultra thick,red] {sin(deg(2*x))};
    \draw[thick] (pi/4,0)--(pi/4,1);
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Presumably same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606539/adding-arrow-draw-to-pgfplot, try e.g. `\draw[thick] (axis cs:pi/4,0) -- (axis cs:pi/4,1);`

Comment: So what code should i use to put a dot?

Comment: You need to be more specific, but seeing as that doesn't have anything to do with your original question, I suggest you do one of two things: either 1) ask a new question about the dot, and we close this one as a duplicate; or 2) you edit the text and title of this question to be about making that dot, instead of the coordinate issue.

Comment: Especially because this question in the comments is related to [a recently closed question by the same author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611559/how-can-i-draw).